# Generate int value from HttpStatusCode

Tags: c#

Here I want to return integer like:

```
{
    "statusCode": "200"
}
```

I am not getting `statuscode` as a integer.

```
var response = new HttpResponseMessage();
response.StatusCode = Request.CreateResponse((HttpStatusCode)200;
```

Comment: `StatusCode` is an Enum, you can use: (int)response.StatusCode

Answer (score 46):

```
Console.Write((int)response.StatusCode);
```

HttpStatusCode (the type of response.StatusCode) is an enumeration where the values of the members match the HTTP status codes, e.g.

```
public enum HttpStatusCode
{
    ...
    Moved = 301,
    OK = 200,
    Redirect = 302,
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 7):

```cs
public int DoHttpOperation(HttpClient client, parameters param)
{
    url = "url which you want to hit";
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("headername", "headervalue");
    var response = //operation which you want to perfrom GET/PUT/POST/DELETE
    return ((int)response.StatusCode);  //Here you will o/p 
}
```